# read properties from property file

Tags: scala

i have a code which loads a properties from 'conf.property' file. Is there a better option to load all properties and store them in e.g. map? Current approach force to add one line of code for each additional property.

```
import java.io.File

object SomeObject {

  // path to the property file
  val path = "/src/main/resources/conf.properties"

  // load configuration from file
  val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(path))


  // get properties
  val prDataPath = conf.getString("dataPath")
  val prContainsHeader = conf.getBoolean("containsHeader").toString
  val prMaxRows: Option[Int]  = Try(conf.getInt("maxRows")).toOption

  // more config variables here...

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [PureConfig](https://pureconfig.github.io)

Your `application.conf`

```
prop1 = "hello"
prop2 = "okidoki"
```

If loaded like in your example than this should work (I haven't tested):

```
import pureconfig.generic.auto._

loadConfig[Map[String, String](conf)
```

You can also create a `case class` that represents your config.

Your example:

```
case class MyConfig(dataPath: String, containsHeader: Boolean, maxRows: Option[Int])
```

Comment: Will check at the evening and let you know, if your solution works perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use json. Just make sure your properties file is in a json format.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import scala.io._

val json = Source.fromFile("/src/main/resources/conf.properties")
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val parsedJson = mapper.readValue[Map[String, Object]](json.reader())
```

Comment: Will check at the evening and let you know, if your solution works perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use HotReload library to convert the conf file to case class https://github.com/gekomad/hot-reload. 
There are two modes: mutable and immutable. The first one creates a configurator that modifies the parameters when the original conf file is modified (automatically hot reload).
The second one allows you to create a configurator that does not change when the original conf file is modified.

```
case class FooConfig(bar: String, baz: Option[Int], list: List[Int], missingValue: Option[String])  

file /path/conf1.conf:  
{  
   bar = "hello",  
   baz = 1,  
   list = [1, 1, 111]  
}  

import com.github.gekomad.hotreload.core.HotReload 

val hr: Try[HotReload[FooConfig]] = HotReload[FooConfig]("/path/conf1.conf")

hr match {  
  case Success(fooConfig) => {        
     assert(fooConfig.currentConf == FooConfig("conf_1", Some(1), List(1, 11, 111), None))
     assert(fooConfig.currentConf.bar == conf1.bar)
     ..
     ..
```